# searching for a key in a bst

Tags: c++, arrays, hashtable

the compiler is telling me that the assertion failed even though I have atleast 2 items in the array of linked nodes. How do I fix this bool contains function? And yes, I have tried multiple ways but I still get the same error.

Keep in mind that there are 2 items in different indexes of the array. But its not shown below.

This is the `contain` function:

```
bool Map::contains(string key){
bool idk = false;

if(elementsStoredCount != 0){
    int idk = hashFunc(key); //the hashFunc computes using modulo

    if(array[found] != nullptr){
        idk = false;
    }
    else{
        found = true;
    }
}


return found;
}
```

when I test in my main.cpp, the second line fails for some reason.

```
assert(as.contains("1")==true);
```

Comment: Provide more information like: a compilable code, input, what output are you getting and what are you expecting etc.

Comment: Guessing here: is the obj goes out of scope? Also this is C++11, not just pure C++

Comment: what does your hashFunc do? what will be the values for idk?

Comment: It seems the error is in `hashFunc`.

Comment: How do you know that the table contains what you claim it's containing?

Comment: *the compiler is telling me that the assertion failed even though I have at least 2 items in the array of linked nodes* -- The `assert` doesn't lie, also, it is a runtime computation, not a compile-time assert.

Comment: Please, provide your hashFunc so that we could understand how you are determining `idk`. Hashing is a suitable place for collision. It could be happened (just guess) that you added `john` and then `abc` and the later overwrote the previous entry.

Comment: *How do I fix this bool contains function?* --  Maybe not fix it, but shorten it instead of all of those `if` branches: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6f5a030931bc089

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You don't need to stop at that verbosity ;-)  – `bool Map::contains(string key) { return elementsStoredCount != 0 && array[hashFunc(key)] != nullptr; }`

Comment: The logic of `contains` is wrong anyway - knowing there's something at a specific bucket (i.e. `array` index) does not guarantee that a particular key has been inserted - another key may have hashed to the same bucket.  Anyway, without showing the `insert` function we've no reason to think that's been done properly.  Voting to close as insufficient code's been pasted despite manetsus' request.

Comment: @manetsus 

i stated how i computed the hashfunc maybe if read it again?

Comment: @programmingblues *i stated how i computed the hashfunc* --  Don't describe.  How about posting the actual code?  If all a programmer needed to do was describe what the code did, there would never be any bugs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Bro fold the fcking key(sum), if you don't know what that means, then mod the size of table

Comment: @programmingblues So the *assert* is a lie?  You did everything correctly, and it is the *assert* that's wrong?  Something is wrong somewhere, and no one is going to know what it is until we see the actual code, not a description.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie its posted

Comment: @programmingblues Is that the code?  Well `sum` is not initialized to 0 before the loop is encountered.  Gotcha.

Comment: Left fold is called "accumulate" in C++; `return std::accumulate(anKey.begin(), anKey.end(), 0) % tableSize;` should do it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have a question about copy constructor and assignment operator for hash tables w/ separate chaining.. I know you'll need a for loop but how would the implementation look like?

Comment: @programmingblues This is why it is important to actually see the code.  Many times a programmer wants to describe what they are doing and could swear that they're doing everything correctly, and won't show the code until prying it out of him / her.  Then bingo, the bug is in the code that was considered flawless.  If I had a dollar for every time this happened, I would be a rich man.

Comment: @programmingblues You need to ask as a separate question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie its posted, do you see it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on some of the other comments and reading the code, i would think that your problem is that your `int hashFunc(string key)` function is returning an incorrect index outside of the range of `array[]`.

Have you debugged/tested taht the `hashFunc()` function to ensure the correct data? If correctly implemented and still you are facing a bug, then i'd next look at your table data/insertion functions.